# When I query Postman I get a response with a status of 200, but in Flutter i get 404, why?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, mobile, request

When I query Postman I get a response with a status of 200 and with the correct body, but in my code I get a 404 response. The server is not mine, it is a well-known bank in my country, so the server should work correctly. Help with my code, I can't understand why I get 404. And I'm sure I'm writing the same data in Postman and in my Flutter code.

I tried via the http package, but same error.

my Flutter code:

```
Future<void> getOrders() async {
  var dio = Dio();

  var url =
      'https://kaspi.kz/shop/api/v2/orders?filter[orders][code]=274556253';

  try {
    var response = await dio.get(
      url,
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
          'X-Auth-Token': '<my token (i have correct token!)>',
        },
      ),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Response data: ${response.data}');
    } else {
      print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
```

**In order to get all the titles and parameters correct, I took the code from Postman:**
[image]

Comment: As answered by @Aiman Khan, it's probably an issue with headers. Most servers have security rules that block requests without the proper headers. Take a look at the headers that Postman uses by default. Adding those one by one until it works would let you know what headers the server requires.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't add an additional header `User-Agent`. Some servers require that header to be set in the request. You can try adding a `User-Agent` header to your request and setting it to a valid value.

Comment: I tried changing User-Agent like Postman's, but it didn't help at all(

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. The error was that Postman was adding the **'Accept' : '*/*'**, but I didn't add it and I don't know what it means.